# PyMySQL table name placeholder

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I know this has been asked a million times, but noone seems to provide an alternative...

So this doesn't work:

```py
DW = pymysql.connect(...)
table = "myTable"
with DW.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM %s", (table,)) # error here
    data = cur.fetchall()
```

Error:

```
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''myTable'' at line 1")
```

`psycopg2` for PostgreSQL has `psycopg2.sql.Identifier` or `AsIs` which basically removes the single quotes and acts as an identifier in the query...is there an equivalent for `pymysql`?

Also, other answers use string formatting and other methods that are vulnerable to SQL injection - this is something I want to avoid.

Comment: Try to replace `"SELECT * FROM %s"` by `"SELECT * FROM :table_name"`.

Comment: Prepared statements does not allow to parametrize the object names.

Comment: modules don't allow to use placeholder for table - all for security reason (queries should use tables hardcoded in SQL) - and you will have to use normal string formatting (`.format()` or `f-string`) to put table in query.

Comment: So basically, there is no way of doing it in `pymysql` and need to use string formatting...